# C# Receive TCP messages while sending

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, .net-core, tcp

I'm having an issue with making an async tcp listener in C# (.NET 6). Basically, I have two computers (one with an IP of 172.22.167.159 and the other with an IP of 172.22.160.1). On the computer with an IP of .160.1, I want to be able to send text to the computer with IP .167.159 while being able to receive messages from it too. Currently, I'm able to send messages to .167.159, but when I try to set up an async function to receive messages (so I can still send while receiving). However, I'm unable to make it work (when I run it, the whole program just doesn't do anything). Below is my code, thanks for the help:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TcpTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create socket to .167.159
            Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse("172.22.167.159");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, 44444);
            soc.Connect(remoteEP);
            Listen(); // listen for text from .167.159 async so input isn't blocked, allowing me to still send text
            // send data to .167.159
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] byData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Console.ReadLine()}\n");
                soc.Send(byData);
            }
        }

        private static async void Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                int port = 44444;
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("172.22.160.1");
                TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
                server.Start();

                byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                string? data = null;

                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    data = null;
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int i;
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received: {data}");
                        data = data.ToUpper();
                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Sent: {data}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See msdn sample code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: Your `Listen()` method is marked with `async`, but does NOT `await` anything. Therefore it is just a plain old SYNCHRONOUS method. Your code never leaves the "listening" while loop. All your program does is continuously accept a connection and receive messages. The "send" part of your code is never hit. If you want to use the synchronous versions of send/receive then you need to put those two loops in different THREADS so you can send and receive at the same time.

Comment: @Idle_Mind thanks, I'll try making different threads